# Is every class, object, and function in c++ standard library declared under namespace std?

Tags: c++, class, object, namespaces, std

Basically the above question. Like are classes like i_stream and everything else included inside the std namespace? Are the istream objects located INSIDE the class istream? Also why is there a namespace if there arent any naming collisions bound to happen?

Comment: Yes. Although the stuff inherited from `c` is at global scope too, for compatibility and ease of implementation. There is a namespace to stop them colliding with your *own* classes and functions (and those of other libraries. E.g. a linear algebra library might have a `vector`)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question in the title,

> “ Is every class, object, and function in c++ standard library declared under namespace std?

no.

For example, the global `operator new` allocation function is in the global namespace only.

Comment: There are also sub-namespaces like std::chrono

Answer (score 2):

Almost.

Here's what my draft of the C++11 standard has to say about it [17.6.1.1, contents]:

> All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete
>   are defined within the namespace std or namespaces nested within
>   namespace std.

So `operator new` and `operator delete` are excluded, even though they are functions.

And there's a footnote there, saying:

> The C standard library headers [...] also define names within
>   the global namespace, while the C++ headers for C library facilities
>   [...] may also define names within the global namespace.

This means that you still have all the [old (now deprecated) C headers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#Deprecated_headers) like `<string.h>` and `<stddef.h>`. Those headers place functions at the global namespace, e.g. `printf`, `strcpy` or `strlen`, just to name a few.

If you use the C++ equivalents of those headers, i.e. `<cstring>`,  `<cstddef>` and so on, then you get those functions in the `std` namespace, so they become `std::printf`, `std::strcpy`, `std::strlen` and so on. But you *may* also get them in the global namespace.

The following is therefore allowed to compile, and probably will when you try it with your favourite compiler:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("Test\n");
    std::printf("Test\n");
}
```

Whereas the following won't:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Test\n");
    std::printf("Test\n"); // error
}
```

---

Regarding your related question:

> Also why is there a namespace if there arent any naming collisions bound to happen?

Use your imagination:

```
Date CreateFromString(std::string const &string);

class OptionsFile
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> list;
    // ...
};

class Buffer
{
    int count;
    // ...
};

Texture::Texture(char const *array);

enum Actions { find, sort };

struct Entity
{
    std::string copy;
};
```